How setup Date field with validation
I use adobe rest API v6. I want to send an agreement to an user with Date field and the date field should have validation. I send the following json. User can see a text field but without formatting. Adobe can validate user's data only if  data has a date format.
Actual: 21.01.2024 - is ok for Adobe but not for me
Expected:  21/01/2024 - is ok for me
I think I need to configure validation & validationData but how to do that? I need a clue.
{

    "name": "Sinatures",
    "signatureType": "ESIGN",
    "state": "IN_PROCESS",
    "status": null,
    "formFieldGenerators": [
        {
            "participantSetName": "unknown",
            "formFieldNamePrefix": "//textu11//",
            "generatorType": "ANCHOR_TEXT",
            "formFieldDescription": {
                "contentType": "DATA",
                "inputType": "TEXT_FIELD",
                "required": true,
                "masked": false,
                "fontName": null,
                "fontColor": null,
                "fontSize": null,
                "displayFormatType" : "DATE",
                "displayFormat": "mm/dd/yyyy",
                "validationData": "mm/dd/yyyy",
                "validation": "DATE_CUSTOM"
            },
            "anchorTextInfo": {
                "anchorText": "//textu11//",
                "anchoredFormFieldLocation": {
                    "height": 20,
                    "width": 150,
                    "offsetX": 20,
                    "offsetY": 0
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


With V6 rest api, you can create the agreement first and then PUT the form field changes separately
PUT /agreements/{agreementId}/formFields HTTP/1.1
authorization: Bearer xxxxx
x-api-user: ""
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "Date Signed",
            "inputType": "TEXT_FIELD",
            "contentType": "SIGNATURE_DATE",
            "required": true,
            "locations": [
                {
                    "height": 20,
                    "width": 150,
                    "left": 20,
                    "top": 0
                }
            ],
            "displayformatType": "DATE",
            "displayFormat": "mm/dd/yyyy",
            "validation": "DATE_CUSTOM",
            "validationData": "mm/dd/yyyy",
            "validationErrMsg": "Invalid Date Format"
        }
    ]
}


src: https://helpx.adobe.com/sign/kb/formfields-option-is-not-available-in-v6-of-rest-api-adobe-sign.html

Sorry it's not working I cannot see date field in a document

also This solution not convinient because I cannoot use anchors

We found out that contentType can be DATE. That's our current solution:
{

    "name": "Sinatures",
    "signatureType": "ESIGN",
    "state": "IN_PROCESS",
    "status": null,
    "formFieldGenerators": [
        {
            "participantSetName": "unknown",
            "formFieldNamePrefix": "//textu11//",
            "generatorType": "ANCHOR_TEXT",
            "formFieldDescription": {
                "contentType": "DATE",
                "inputType": "TEXT_FIELD",
                "required": true,
                "masked": false,
                "fontName": null,
                "fontColor": null,
                "fontSize": null,
                "validation": "DATE_CUSTOM",
                "validationData": "mm/dd/yyyy"
            },
            "anchorTextInfo": {
                "anchorText": "//textu11//",
                "anchoredFormFieldLocation": {
                    "height": 20,
                    "width": 150,
                    "offsetX": 20,
                    "offsetY": 0
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

